# shell script: Returning wrong output

Tags: bash, jq

In the given script, the nested key is not getting appended with the value. I could not figure out where the script is going wrong.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

echo "Add the figma json file path"
read path

figma_json="$(echo -e "${path}" | tr -d '[:space:]')"

echo $(cat $figma_json | jq -r '.color | to_entries[] | "\(.key):\(.value| if .value == null then .[] | .value  else .value end)"')
```

Sample input:

```json
{
  "color": {
    "white": {
      "description": "this is just plain white color",
      "type": "color",
      "value": "#ffffffff",
      "extensions": {
        "org.lukasoppermann.figmaDesignTokens": {
          "styleId": "S:40940df38088633aa746892469dd674de8b147eb,",
          "exportKey": "color"
        }
      }
    },
    "gray": {
      "50": {
        "description": "",
        "type": "color",
        "value": "#fafafaff",
        "extensions": {
          "org.lukasoppermann.figmaDesignTokens": {
            "styleId": "S:748a0078c39ca645fbcb4b2a5585e5b0d84e5fd7,",
            "exportKey": "color"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Actual output:

```
white:#ffffffff gray:#fafafaff
```

Excepted output:

```
white:#ffffffff gray:50:#fafafaff
```

[Full input file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1j5Ola25ylaY1TWxe-OE7iSIYokF6fPz0/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Don't use `echo -e` unless you **really** know you need to. (And really, don't use it even then; if you really need its effects, `printf '%b\n'` is the better alternative, even suggested in the `echo` standards documentation). In particular, `echo -e` with a JSON string can make it into something that's no longer valid JSON, by replacing literal `\n` sequences with newlines.

Comment: BTW, why is your actual output code-formatted but your expected output not? It makes it hard to compare them.

Comment: ...beyond that, what part of your jq code is **supposed** to add the `:50` to the output? I don't see any code that would be reasonably expected to do that?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I have highlighted the output code to make reader's easier.

Comment: It's the opposite of easier, unless you highlight them both the same way.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy As the code parse's deeper the inner dict key to be appended with parentKey. Here not able to get the inner dict key

Comment: Then it's not "could not figure out where the script going wrong", it's "could not figure out how to modify the script to ...add this feature..." that would have been a more descriptive/helpful way to ask the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution using `tostream` instead of `to_entries` to facilitate simultaneous access to the full path and its value:

```sh
jq -r '
  .color | tostream | select(.[0][-1] == "value" and has(1)) | .[0][:-1]+.[1:] | join(":")
' "$figma_json"
```

```
white:#ffffffff
gray:50:#fafafaff
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/JcB3N3mWyb)

Answer (score 1):

An approach attempting to demonstrate bash best-practices:

```
#!/bin/bash

figma_json=$1                              # prefer command-line arguments to prompts
[[ $figma_json ]] || {
  read -r -p 'Figma JSON file path: ' path # read -r means backslashes not munged
  figma_json=${path//[[:space:]]/}         # parameter expansion is more efficient than tr
}

jq -r '
  def recurse_for_value($prefix):
    to_entries[]
    | .key as $current_key
    | .value?.value? as $immediate_value
    | if $immediate_value == null then
        .value | recurse_for_value(
                   if $prefix != "" then
                     $prefix + ":" + $current_key
                   else
                     $current_key
                   end
                 )
      else
        if $prefix == "" then
          "\($current_key):\($immediate_value)"
        else
          "\($prefix):\($current_key):\($immediate_value)"
        end
      end
    ;
  .color |
  recurse_for_value("")
' "$figma_json"
```